# getElementByClass from HTML fetched from an external source -> undefined

Tags: angular

Im fetching html blocks from an external source using HTTP get and insert it in my application with innerHTML function. Im trying to access a div class by its class name with getElementsByClassName. This is how the respons looks like:

[image]

When i try to access one of the objects in the list with indexing,(ex result[0]), I get back undefined. Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks!

update:

I've found what the issue was. The html had not been properly initialized before i tried to access it.

This is my function that fetches html block from my service class.

```
  getNewsFeed(){
      this.homeService.getNewsFeed()
      .subscribe(res =>
        this.news_block = res,
        error=>this.news_feed_error=true,
        ()=>  this.news_feed_error=false
      );
```

getNewsfeed is executed from:

```
ngOnInit(){
      this.getNewsFeed();
}
```

I run getElementByClassName in ngAfterViewInit

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
      console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("overlayWrapper"));

    }
```

I load the answer from getNewsFeed() into my selector with:

```
<div *ngIf="news_block" [innerHtml]="news_block"></div>
```

Comment: Please show some actual code that demonstrates what you're doing. Ideally a plunker that allows to reproduce.

Comment: Ive found what the problem was, the html had not been properly initialized before i tried to access it. First i executed the function in ngOnInit. I've tried to use ngAfterViewInit() but that did not solve my problem. Do you got any suggestions?

Comment: As mentioned without seeing some actual code it's hard to make suggestions.

Comment: I've updated my post with code examples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observable returns the data async and then the callback passed to `.subscribe()` is executed.

There is no guarantee when or even if the data will arrive. There is no Angular callback that can guarantee that `getNewsFeed()` has returned any result.

Not optimal but should be an improvment:

```
getNewsFeed(){
  this.homeService.getNewsFeed()
  .subscribe(res => {
      this.news_block = res;
      setTimeout(() => checkElement();
    },

    error=>this.news_feed_error=true,
    ()=>  this.news_feed_error=false
  ); 
}

checkElement(){
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("overlayWrapper"));

}
```

This way it's at least ensured the HTML has actually been received when `getElementsByClassName()` is called.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thanks a bunch for the answer!

Comment: Glad to hear. Thanks for the feedback :)